# Java Client To WebRTC

Tags: java, webrtc

Is there a library or way to take WebRTC and put it into a java application. Meaning the **client** is entirely on the desktop, javafx. It then uses the networking technology of WebRTC to connect two applications. I could use the entire WebRTC server as usual to handle these two applications.

Just curious. Thanks.

Comment: Usually library recommendations are [off-topic for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This is more of a question that involves whether it is really possible I suppose, as WebRTC has been written for the browser. Though it is also a communication protocol; nevertheless, it might not be feasible. Nevertheless, if I don't get an answer soon I can remove it.

Comment: Take a look at Jitst project (only support Android but has full stack implementation in Java)

Comment: Kind of the same as [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102180/is-there-a-webrtc-java-peer-client-library)

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse its possible . you want a webrtc endpoint to connect to a RTP endpoint isnt it ? Here you need a VP8 to H264 media converter which takes live stream from webrtc source , puts it on a desktop application and vice versa . Use GStreamer java libraries .