# Is there a WebRTC Java peer client library?

Tags: webrtc, kurento

Is there a peer client for Java to use for WebRTC? I'm currently using Kurento to stream video/audio between to browser clients. In addition, I want to attach another peer client to receive the video stream in my Java service. Is this possible? I couldn't find any WebRTC peers that uses Java.

Comment: https://jitsi.org ?

Comment: https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/tutorials/java/tutorial-magicmirror.html , Have you tried this ?

Comment: Try this working very well in my project: https://developer.enablex.io/api/client-api/

Comment: Kurento Doc uses a Kurento Client SDK which isn't a WebRTC peer client. That library simply calls KMS APIs.

Comment: @9dan does jitsilib support webrtc? couldn't find any conclusive information...

Answer (score 4):

- [WebRTC Java/Android](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) or
- Gradle `implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'` or
- [Bintray](https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc) or
- [Codename One webRTC](https://github.com/shannah/CN1WebRTC) for Android, iOS, JavaScript and Desktop

There is the version for Android, but you can use it anywhere. You can also download the source code & compile it from the first link (I don't imagine is the case).

The version for Codename One works everywhere but depends on the app being a Codename One app.

Comment: "There is only this version for Android, but you can use it anywhere." - are you sure? I'd imaging it would have require platform support - have you tried to use it on the desktop with, let's say Swing or JavaFX?

Comment: @Wojtek you might be right. I only tested on Android so for Swing/JavaFX it might not work.

Comment: Edited and added the new webRTC implementation from Codename One to the answer

Comment: First link is dead tho